# Trying to call a Future function inside of a child of a ListView

Tags: flutter

trying to create a app usage app in flutter.
In the following code, I'm calling the **appNameProvider()** function inside of the child element of **ListView**. And returning the appName to the child. problem is that instead of the value for that function, it prints **Instances of 'Future<String>'**

```
List<AppUsageInfo> infoList = await AppUsage.getAppUsage(startDate, endDate);
     setState(() {
       _infos = infoList;});

Future<String> appNameProvider(pn) async {
   Application apps = await DeviceApps.getApp(pn);
   return apps.appName;
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: const Text("Usage Stats"),
       ),
       body: ListView.builder(
         itemCount: _infos.length,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           return ListTile(
               title: Text(_infos[index].packageName.toString()),
               subtitle: Text(_infos[index].usage.toString()),
               trailing: Text("${appNameProvider(_infos[index].packageName.toString())}"),

           );
         }),
```

[image]

Comment: Future type functions need `await` to receive the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FutureBuilder for calling appNameProvider since it returns a Future.

```dart
trailing: FutureBuilder(
  future: appNameProvider(_infos[index].packageName.toString()),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.data != null) {
      return Text(snapshot.data);
    }
    return Text('No Data');
  },
),
```